# Java process freezes until I use 100% CPU

Tags: arch-linux, java, eclipse, intellij

#### The issue I encounter

When working on Android-Studio, Eclipse or even command-line Gradle, the Java software often freezes (even though usually it is after I update my system/change java). For Android-Studio and Eclipse, if I move to another desktop and come back, then it becomes a gray window and the interface never comes back, even after hours. I suppose it is a Java issue.

It does not always happen: I usually don't have any problem for weeks until it appears again. I don't understand what makes it stop: when it happens, I try to reboot my computer, change my Java JDK version, but it does not change anything. Then one day, I boot my computer and the problem has disappeared - for the next few weeks.

#### What I can observe

- One CPU always stays at 100%
- I cannot make a thread dump of Android-Studio (as described [here](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-260)): it freezes as well.
- If I run **a big C++ compilation** while Android-Studio/Eclipse/Gradle is freezing (i.e. a compilation that takes all of my CPUs), then it stops freezing and I can continue my work until the next time (but it happens extremely often).

#### What I tried

- I tried another Window Manager: I could reproduce the bug on XMonad and Fluxbox
- I tried to `export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1` in `/etc/profile.d/jre.sh`
- I tried to switch between `java-7-jdk`, `java-7-openjdk`, `java-8-jdk`, `java-8-openjdk`
- I tried to run `wmname LG3D`
- I tried to run `pkill -e adb`, as advised in the comments
- I tried to `jmap <pid>` on the `<pid>` of Android Studio, but I have a *"DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process"*
- I tried to `jcmd <pid> GC.run` on the `<pid>` of Android Studio, but I have a *"DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process" and "Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded"*.
- I tried to remove my `.gradle` directory
- I tried to `Invalidate and Restart` Android Studio (but the problem does not look to be unique to Android Studio since I experienced it with Eclipse, too)

#### My configuration

I am on Arch Linux (but a similar issue has been reported on Linux Mint) with Awesome WM (I experience the same with XMonad and Fluxbox). As far as I remember, it has always been happening on this machine (I changed in October 2014). Before this, it was working on Debian (but with Awesome WM as well). I have updated Android-Studio many times (from around 0.8 to the latest version).

What could be happening? Or how can I figure out?

#### Related problems

I have recently found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463592/1368342) talking about a similar problem. I tried what he advises (i.e. I tried `export LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.4.1; android-studio`) but then Android Studio does not start at all. Is it possible that I also have a problem with NPTL?

Comment: The same for me on Linux Mint 17.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. Any updates?

Comment: I cannot say that this solved the problem, but I used the "File > invalidate cache and restart..." option from the menus (or something like that, I don't have it on top of my head). I also removed the ".gradle" directory. Which window manager do you use?

Comment: Now I use Cinnamon, but the same thing was on Unity and Gnome on Ubuntu 14.04. So it seems to be some common Android Studio issue for multiple Linux OS.

Comment: I also use "File > Power Save Mode" in Android Studio and seems it works much better with this option on, but it is very hard to work with it, because Android Studio is very limited and not highlighting code.

Comment: Did you try to invalidate the cache and restart?

Comment: No, but I think that it will still appear later even if I invalidate the cache and restart, so I will need to do it again and again. Android Studio loads CPU and freezes so much that I can't even move the mouse for a couple of minutes, so I think it would be hard to press it even if it will freeze :)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: pkill -e adb if it reports it killed it, re-run the command until there's no more adb, use android studio as necessary and when you need to test, adb will be started by the IDE

Comment: So you think adb is freezing Java?

Comment: I am just experiencing the problem again, and `pkill -e adb` does not solve it, unfortunately.

Comment: @YuriyYunikov: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I had to install Android Studio on Windows to make it run normally :(

Comment: How is the Ram before, during large C++ compilation which unfreezes the JVM? Curious about Max Heap space. Also, is problem reproduced for fresh user, home folder? Have found fresh user account, Eclipse, other toolkits download helpful when at a loss.

Comment: Before the large C++ compilation, the ram is staying around 2330-2350MB. During the compilation which unfreezes the JVM, it goes up to ~2800MB. I have 32GB on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the answer to this question, but this problem hasn't occured in months (maybe a year?).

I guess something fixed it, somehow.

I will therefore close the question now.

Answer (score 0):

In the Environment Variables settings in eclipse create a System Variable called _JAVA_OPTIONS with the value -Xms256m -Xmx1024m or change the existing one to these values. This assumes you have sufficient memory available.

Comment: Still freezing, with -Xms1024m and -Xmx4096m =/